# Issue with parameterized queries in a MySQL site search

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, sql, sql-injection

I'm trying to create a simple site search using c# ASP.NET and MySQL, and I'm trying to use parameterized queries to prevent SQL injection. There's a lot of info out there already but I still can't get this to work, can anyone see what's wrong with my code? Is there a library I'm not referencing perhaps?

Here's my current code:

```
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

string q = Request["q"].IsEmpty() ? "" : Request["q"];

List<dynamic> MyList = new List<dynamic>();

using(MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection("server=localhost;database=database;user id=user;password=password"))
{
    string sql = "SELECT * FROM Items WHERE Name = @Name";
    con.Open(); 

    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql,con);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", q);        

    MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader(); 

    while(reader.Read()){ 
        MyList.Add(new {
            Value = reader["Value"].ToString()
        });

    con.Close();

}
```

If I swap the sql parameter for an actual value in the database, it does return items, such as the following:

```
    string sql = "SELECT * FROM Items WHERE Name = 'aValue'";
```

Comment: Do you get any errors or it just doesn't return any data?

Comment: Hey Sam - just no data returned!

Comment: debug and see variable q has 'aValue'...

Comment: yeah, the q variable has the correct intended value

Answer (score 0):

```
while(reader.Read()){ 
    MyList.Add(new {
        Value = reader["Value"].ToString()
    });
```

I think there may be some typos in the code above - not sure if this is copied exactly from your source - but you may be missing a closing } for youe while loop

Also, it's good practice to use

```
  using(MySqlDataReader Reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()) 
  {
    ...
  }
```

just like you did for the mySqlConnection object to save a memory leak (but this is not your problem.)